# Why this Mayavi animation stops executing at a random iteration?

Tags: mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I read a few questions similar to mine but none of the answers work... I want to make an animation that plots the points of a list one by one. The problem is that from rank 12, it stops. I tested gc.collect(generation=1) but it didn't work... Here is the end of my code :

```
@mlab.animate(delay=100)
def updateAnimation():
   k=0
   for k in range(len(X)):
      mlab.points3d(X[k], Y[k], Z[k], S[k], color=C[k], scale_factor=10)
      yield

updateAnimation()
mlab.show()
```

X, Y, Z, S and C are lists with a length of 136. I am using python 3.9.12 and mayavi 4.8.0. It's maybe something stupid with set... but I'm new at mayavi.

Thank you very much for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
p3d = mlab.points3d(X[0], Y[0], Z[0], S[0], color=C[0], scale_factor=10)

@mlab.animate(delay=100)
def updateAnimation():
   k=0
   for k in range(len(X)):
      p3d.set(x=X[k], y=Y[k], z=Z[k], s=S[k], color=C[k])
      yield

ua = updateAnimation()
mlab.show()
```

`

This (untested code) is prettymuch a copy from here http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html#id10

You create the visualization once and update it in the updateAnimation procedure. The `ua = updateAnimation()` stores the result in a variable so that the animation keeps running even if it is called from an asynchronous coroutine. You use `set()` if the shape of your data remains the same and `reset()` otherwise. This works with point3d and plot3d but unfortunately not with all plots in mlab.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?